# HEREDOC in Dockerfile produces no output

Tags: docker, bash, shell, zsh, heredoc

I have this command that I am trying to run in a `Dockerfile` and it is producing no output to the file:

```
FROM alpine:3.19 as base

RUN <<-EOF > /root/.npmrc
    registry=https://\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}
    strict-ssl=false
    always-auth=true
    email=\${PUBLISHER_EMAIL}
    //\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}:_auth=\${NPM_BASIC_AUTH}
EOF
RUN ls -al /root && cat $HOME/.npmrc
```

Produces:

```
docker build -t base --target=base .
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

Sending build context to Docker daemon  946.2kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.19 as base
 ---> 05455a08881e
Step 2/3 : RUN <<-EOF > /root/.npmrc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f18fb43d4ffa
Step 3/3 : RUN ls -al /root && cat $HOME/.npmrc
 ---> Running in 24b3b8f942a8
total 8
drwx------    1 root     root          4096 Jan 30 02:55 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 30 02:55 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Jan 30 02:55 .npmrc
Removing intermediate container 24b3b8f942a8
 ---> 7b21305b1704
Successfully built 7b21305b1704
Successfully tagged base:latest
```

And, if I try to output it from the CLI, same deal:

```
-> % docker run -it base cat /root/.npmrc                  
[18:57:04] [~/dev/app] [CES-2242_refactor-pipeline_build *]
-> %
```

But, if I run this same command on the cli of my laptop (Mac OS 14.3):

```
[18:58:34] [~/dev/app] [CES-2242_refactor-pipeline_build *]
-> % <<-EOF > .npmrc      
    registry=https://\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}
    strict-ssl=false
    always-auth=true
    email=\${PUBLISHER_EMAIL}
    //\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}:_auth=\${NPM_BASIC_AUTH}
EOF
[18:58:45] [~/dev/app] [CES-2242_refactor-pipeline_build *]
-> % cat .npmrc
    registry=https://${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}
    strict-ssl=false
    always-auth=true
    email=${PUBLISHER_EMAIL}
    //${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}:_auth=${NPM_BASIC_AUTH}
```

it works fine. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
I remove the `BUILD_KIT=0` flag I had earlier. Makes no difference

Comment: HEREDOC support was added in BuildKit recently and you are disabling BuildKit with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write a file. I'm pretty sure the RUN HEREDOC syntax is for running commands.

Comment: @BMitch - heredoc follow all heredoc syntax I see online

Comment: @AlexD - I removed the BUILD_KIT=0 and it made no difference. Is there a better exchange to post this question?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing this command:

```
RUN <<-EOF > /root/.npmrc
    registry=https://\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}
    strict-ssl=false
    always-auth=true
    email=\${PUBLISHER_EMAIL}
    //\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}:_auth=\${NPM_BASIC_AUTH}
EOF
```

I believe the result is a shell running the following commands in a container:

```shell
> /root/.npmrc
registry=https://\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}
strict-ssl=false
always-auth=true
email=\${PUBLISHER_EMAIL}
//${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}:_auth=${NPM_BASIC_AUTH}
```

That's one command to output nothing to a `.npmrc` file, followed by 5 separate commands to set a variable in the shell, at which point the shell exits and loses all of that variable state.

To output to a file, there's a COPY syntax with the HEREDOC support:

```
COPY <<-EOF /root/.npmrc
    registry=https://\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}
    strict-ssl=false
    always-auth=true
    email=\${PUBLISHER_EMAIL}
    //\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}:_auth=\${NPM_BASIC_AUTH}
EOF
```

Or you can run a command inside the container that would itself do the HEREDOC, which may do a better job with variables:

```
RUN <<EORUN
    cat <<-EOCAT > /root/.npmrc
    registry=https://\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}
    strict-ssl=false
    always-auth=true
    email=\${PUBLISHER_EMAIL}
    //\${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}:_auth=\${NPM_BASIC_AUTH}
EOCAT
EORUN
```

Comment: I'll try this later. I was originally using cat for this and got similar results.